# Show DIV before refresh

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a webpage that is auto-refreshed every 240 seconds with the generic HTML Meta tag. During the refresh it pulls data from a database which takes the site about 15 to 20 seconds to build before it's shown to the user. During this time I wish to show a small DIV with a loading message telling the user that it's loading data.
The more complicated thing about this is that the user has a few menu options to filter out specific data from the database. When clicking such an option the page is reloaded again and takes 15 to 20 seconds to build.

Users that aren't familiar with this loading time might feel the need to click the same menu option over and over again within a few seconds hoping that the page will load faster. But instead it will most likely cause the database server to get overloaded with requests.

So, to tackle this I wish to use jQuery to show a loading message, then have it load the data from the database (with a PHP script) and finally dump the data on the page.

I've done something similar but that was limited to users clicking a link which caused a jQuery script to load the data while showing the waiting DIV (using CSS rules).

I can't figure out how to implement this solution for an auto-refresh.

Some help would be nice.

Comment: maybe sharing what you have so far?

Comment: Don't do a full refresh and just update page segments that may of been changed via ajax. It will allow the site to continue working while the request goes through

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same solution with auto-refresh as well, with the mention that the initial page load doesn't container the data that requires the DB call, but instead shows a loading message and starts an AJAX call to a server side script that returns the data.

**Your page load:**

1. Request
2. Server query DB
3. DB Response
4. Page loads (with data)

**Ideal page load:**

1. Request
2. Page loads (without data) <- loading message here
3. AJAX call
4. Server query DB
5. DB Response
6. Page updates (with data)

Answer (score 0):

I'd second megawac's comment.  Don't use a meta refresh.  Also, 15-20 seconds is a *very long* time for generating a database report that is going to be generated every 4 minutes; odds are that you're bogging down your server pretty badly.  Very few queries should really take that long, especially queries that need to be run nearly continually.  I would *strongly* recommend refactoring your queries or doing some caching to speed things up.  If you post some code, I'm sure people would be happy to look at it.